# using Angular JS /REACT in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, angularjs, react

As we all know that LWC is built on Web Standard (jUst like REACT JS,Angular Js ), so is it necessary to use these front end technologies in our Salesforce Application.
As an architect ,do we  need to incorporate  Angular JS/REACT etc in our application?
Also as a LWC learner do we need to learn REACT/ANGULAR also ,or just LWC is fine?

Comment: It's no necessary to learn these technologies, but have good knowledge of ES6+, is really helpful. I don't think we need to use these technologies in salesforce unless there is a very strong business reason, or you are not able to achieve something using LWC, which reduces lots of work. Also, LWC has a vast library of prebuilt components. Again there is no harm in knowing these technologies, its good.

Comment: @rahulgawale As per ur answer i think i cam mange without learning REACT or Angular.Thnx.

Comment: Yes, you can!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Learning React or Angular will not directly help you learn LWC, nor will learning LWC help you learn these other two technologies. They are all just different enough that you'll find they are more different than they are similar. There's no need to learn React or Angular to use LWC. As an example, I have learned LWC and have never so much as programmed a simple React app (though I have used Angular, and it's definitely not anything like LWC).

Comment: Thnx for the clarification. Was just worried if some projects involve the use of Angular etc. Any ways thnx for the clarification